# Use struct as index into vector

Tags: octave

Is there a "better"(means readable and vectorized) method to use a struct with indices to generate a result struct?

```
# struct values are indices into b
a.foo = 2;
a.bar = 3;

b = [e pi 123 1337];

## the loopy way
for [val, key] = a
  c.(key) = b(val);
endfor

disp (c)
```

which gives the desired result

```
scalar structure containing the fields:

  foo =  3.1416
  bar =  123
```

or another clumsy and almost obfuscated way:

```
d = cell2struct(num2cell(b([struct2cell(a){:}])'), fieldnames(a));
assert (c, d);
```

Comment: You know "s### just got real" when Andy is _asking_ an octave question here :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, the lovely one-liner you're looking for is probably:

```
structfun (@ (x) b(x), a, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

However, structfun, much like its other 'fun' relatives, seems to be just syntactic sugar rather than actual vectorisation. So in fact the fastest (and arguably cleanest) method does seem to be your for loop:

Benchmark:

```
octave:1>  a.foo = 2; a.bar = 3; b = [e pi 123 1337];
```

```
octave:2>  # loop method #
        >  tic; for i = 1 : 100; 
        >    for [val, key] = a; S1.(key) = b(val); end; 
        >  end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.00160003 seconds.
```

```
octave:3>  # cell2struct method # 
        >  tic; for i = 1 : 100; 
        >    S2 = cell2struct(num2cell(b([struct2cell(a){:}])'), fieldnames(a));
        >  end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.006423 seconds.
```

```
octave:4>  # structfun method #
        >  tic; for i = 1: 100
        >    S3 = structfun(@ (x) b(x), a, 'UniformOutput', false);
        >  end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.279853 seconds.
```

<sub>PS. However, note that the for-loop approach will *not* work "*as is*" if you have an *array* of structs, whereas the structfun approach will.</sub>

Comment: I didn't thought about `structfun` which uses `cellfun` under the hood. And I'm puzzled that it's so slow... Btw, if you want to make benchmarks you should preallocate an array and store the `toc` result inside the loop into it. At the end you can run `std` and `mean`. This eliminates the overhead for the loop from the measurement.